# Price should be calculated on base of weight too

Tags: magento

I have a product Like apple. For 1 Kg apple, price is 5$. Now,the apples are available in 3 boxes.that is 1kg apple box,2kg apple box and 5 kg apple box.

So, Customer will select which box he want to purchase and then enter quantity of boxes.

So final price will be weight of box ** quantity of boxes ** price of 1kg apple.

So how should I create this product in magento backend?

I have used option but in custom options I need to enter price for 2 kg and 5kg. but logically I think that when I specify price for 1kg then it should take price for 2kg and 5kg on based of unit price of 1 kg.

Please,advise best approach to create this type of product.

Comment: Is this a programming related question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but  [Matrix Rate Magento Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html) with weight vs destination type will solve your problem.

just add this extension and choose weight vs destination and upload csv file for your rules. i hope it'll work.